# Authentication failed when trying to connect to my MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to set up a MongoDB server running from a windows server, preferably it needs to be as secure as possible. I added the users I want, using the following method:

```
cd program files/mongodb/server/4.0/bin

mongo

use <specific database>

db.createUser({user: "<userid>", pwd: "<userpassword>", roles: [{ role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin"}]})
```

It will then add the user, if I repeat the line it says the user already exists...so the login is set up right?

However when I connect to the database using the following command it returns authentication failed:

`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo --host <host> --port <port> -u <userid> -p <userpwd>`

Am I doing something wrong in the way I have setup the user login details or the way I connect using the credentials?

thanks

Comment: have you tried `db.auth()` from within the mongo shell?

Comment: @Intellidroid I have just tried it, it returns `authentication failed` and error code `0`

Comment: so you are doing `use <specific database> db.Auth(<username> , <password>)`

Comment: also have you tried `db.getUser()`?

Comment: You need to specify in what database your credentials info are. Normally they're in the admin db. So just inform this in your connect call: ```mongo localhost --username user --authenticationDatabase admin -p```